# How to remove a selected object item that exist in the localStorage key?

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me with this plz?
I have items in the basketItems key which are individual objects, I simply want to iterate through this key "basketItems" and remove the selected objet item.

[image: A picture of localStorage key]

Comment: *>..I simply want..* any progress further than wanting so far?

Comment: Get the value from local storage, use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object, use `findIndex()` to get the index in the array that matches your criteria, use `splice()` to remove that element from the array, convert it back to JSON, and write it back to local storage.

Comment: Actually the basketItems key is an object of objects ! it's not an array !

Answer (score 4):

First Get the value of `basketItems` from Local Storage, then parse it to JSON, delete the key from the JSON and save the object back to Local Storage.

```js
let basketItems = localStorage.getItem("basketItems");
basketItems = JSON.parse(basketItems);

delete basketItems.Katatone;

basketItems = JSON.stringify(basketItems);
localStorage.setItem("basketItems", basketItems);
```

Comment: It removes the key specified manually but i want to iterate through these keys which are objects and remove the selected object when a condition is meat ?!

Comment: Iterate through it just like you would for any javascript object. I can only help you if I know what conditions are you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the old value by `getItem`, it is a string at first, turn it to JSON with `parse`

```
const result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basketItems"));
```

Delete the key value pair with `delete`

```
delete result.Katatone;
```

Finally, override old local storage value with the new result:

```
localStorage.setItem('basketItems', JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: @Mohammad Dohadwala posted the answer faster, we have the same approach, I'm upvoting his answer :)